# Find minimum number of coins that make a given value, I'm trying to solve this for float coin values instead of integer coin values in Rust

Tags: rust, dynamic-programming

Problem Statement: Write a function that returns the smallest number of coins needed to make change for the target amount using the given coin denominations.

I'm trying to convert the below *i32* `integer-based` [solution](https://github.com/michealkeines/Rust/blob/main/Ds_Algos/Algorithms/min_coin_change/src/main.rs) to `float` *f32* or *f64* based solution so it can take decimal input such as coin denomination of 0.5, 1.5, 2.0 etc.

```
use std::cmp;

fn min_number_of_change(n: i32, denoms: Vec<u32>) -> i32 {
    let mut ways: Vec<i32> = vec![i32::MAX;n as usize + 1];
    ways[0] = 0;

    for denom in denoms.iter() {
        for current in 0..ways.len() {
            if *denom <= current as u32 {
                ways[current as usize] = cmp::min(ways[current as usize], 1 + ways[current as usize - *denom as usize]) 
                                  
            }
        }
    }
    if ways[n as usize] != i32::MAX {
        ways[n as usize]
    } else {
          -1
    }
}
fn main() {
    let denoms: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 5, 10, 2, 3];
    let n: i32 = 6;

    let result: i32 = min_number_of_change(n, denoms);
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

[Play Ground for above code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e23b58959439f4934b4e14f4b580682e)

Very naively I've tried replacing `i32` with `f32` and [min](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.min:%7E:text=pub%20fn%20min(self%2C%20other%3A%20f32)%20%2D%3E%20f32) function to get the float comparisons. When running it, the Compiler complains about mismatched types, cannot subtract `f32` from `usize`, the type `[f32]` cannot be indexed by `f32`. I think I'm missing some very fundamental points.

```
fn min_number_of_change(n: f32, denoms: Vec<f32>) -> f32 {
    let mut ways: Vec<f32> = vec![f32::INFINITY; n + 1.0];
    ways[0] = 0.0;

    for denom in denoms.iter() {
        for current in 0..ways.len() {
            if *denom <= current {
                ways[current] = (ways[current].min(1 + ways[current  - *denom ]), 1 + ways[current  - *denom ])
            }
        }
    }
    if ways[n] != f32::INFINITY {
        ways[n]
    } else {
        -1.0
    }
}


fn main() {
    let denoms: Vec<f32> = vec![2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
    let n: f32 = 4.55;

    let result: f32 = min_number_of_change(n, denoms);
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

[Playground for above code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a961aa8d62bd478137a77a36619fb351)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is simple to fix. Instead of `current - *denom` you can write `current as f32 - *denom`.

But that leaves us with the second error which is harder.
You can't index a `Vec` with a `f32` because that would require to acces the `0.5`th element, an element half an elements width away from the first one. This is simply not possible.

Your best bet is probably using integers and treating them as fixed point values i.e. `1` means `0.01` in your currency etc.

```rust
fn main() {
    let denoms = [2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01].into_iter().map(|v| (v * 100.0) as i32).collect();
    let n = (4.55 * 100.0) as i32;
    let result = min_number_of_change(n, denoms) as f32 / 100.0;
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

and use the integer version of `min_number_of_change`